# jQuery.parseJSON not working on Ajax Success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

i am trying to parse json data which i get in response but using jQuery.parseJSON it is not working.
Ajax Success not Working if i remove the below data from comment in Ajax Success Callback Function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Working Example in Comment
    //var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "harsh","address":["add1","add2"] }' );
    //var objArray = obj.address;
    //alert(objArray[2]);

    $('#getData').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'JsonServlet',
                type:'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    //var JSONdata = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    //alert(JSONdata);

                    $('#name').val(data.name);
                    $('#email').val(data.email);
                    $("#add").val(data.innerJSONObj1.address);
                }
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: As you have specified the data type as `'json'`, you shouldn't parse the data. It is already parsed before the `success` callback is called.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What is the value of `data`? What is the data type of `data` (`alert(typeof data)`)? Do the three uncommented statements in the success function work with the code as it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since you specify dataType: 'json', the data variable is already a json object.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

> If json is specified, the response is parsed using jQuery.parseJSON before being passed, as an object, to the success handler. The parsed JSON object is made available through the responseJSON property of the jqXHR object.

Comment: "the data variable is already a json" — No, it is not. JSON is the data format. Given that code, it should have been converted **from** JSON into a JavaScript object.

Comment: @Quentin i missed the word "object", but you know what i meant.

Comment: It isn't a JSON object. It isn't JSON. It was a string containing JSON. Then it got parsed. That turned it into a JavaScript object.